how to solve this error webiste url was loaded over HTTPS
https://websitename/login' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure resource 'http://here port/api/user/login'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.
i try to login but get this error https://websitename/login' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure resource 'http://here port/api/user/login'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
